# Magento 2.3 remove other shipping methods and enable only free shipping if the amount is more than 99

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Tell me how you can hide the rest of the delivery methods and leave only free if the order amount is more than 99

I tried the implementation that is on the stack for lower versions, it either does not work or is deprecated, I need it for version 2.3

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `di.xml` file in your custom module here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Shipping\Model\CarrierFactory">
        <plugin name="free_shipping_above_99" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\CarrierFactory" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Now you need to create one `Plugin` file here in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Model/CarrierFactory.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model;

class CarrierFactory
{
    /**
     * Core store config
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;

    protected $_checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $_checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $_checkoutSession;
    }

    public function aroundGet(
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\CarrierFactory $subject,
        $Closure,
        $carrierCode
    ) {
        /*Change your logic here based on your requirement.*/
        $grandTotal = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
        if($grandTotal > 99 && $carrierCode != 'freeshipping'){
            return false;
        }
        /*Change your logic here based on your requirement.*/

        $className = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'carriers/' . $carrierCode . '/model',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
        if (!$className) {
            return false;
        }
        $carrier = $this->_objectManager->get($className);
        $carrier->setId($carrierCode);
        return $carrier;
    }

    public function aroundCreate(
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\CarrierFactory $subject,
        $Closure,
        $carrierCode,
        $storeId = null
    ) {
        /*Change your logic here based on your requirement.*/
        $grandTotal = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
        if($grandTotal > 99 && $carrierCode != 'freeshipping'){
            return false;
        }
        /*Change your logic here based on your requirement.*/

        $className = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'carriers/' . $carrierCode . '/model',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $storeId
        );
        if (!$className) {
            return false;
        }
        $carrier = $this->_objectManager->create($className);
        $carrier->setId($carrierCode);
        if ($storeId) {
            $carrier->setStore($storeId);
        }
        return $carrier;
    }
}
```

You can change your logic in **Plugin** based on your requirements, this will work when order's grand total is more than 99 then it will only display **FREE SHIPPING** and if order total is below 99 then it will display all other shipping methods and not display FREE SHIPPING there.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks, you very help me

Comment: Can you please upvote for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Disable the free shipping delivery method. Add the free shipping functionality (more than 99) through a cart price rule.